# NameError: name 'runfile' is not defined only when running from script

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, nameerror

sima.py

```
import pyautogui as py
py.alert("Foo")
```

simaref.py

```
runfile('E:/Anyagok/Programozas/Python/projekts/gyak/Pyautogui/sima.py', 
        wdir='E:/Anyagok/Programozas/Python/projekts/gyak/Pyautogui')
```

These both work when running from Spyder.

sima.py works from cmd as well:

```
python.exe E:\Anyagok\Programozas\Python\projekts\gyak\Pyautogui\sima.py
```

But simaref.py doesn't:

```
E:\Download\PROGIK\ANACONDA>python.exe E:\Anyagok\Programozas\Python\projekts\gyak\Pyautogui\simaref.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Anyagok\Programozas\Python\projekts\gyak\Pyautogui\simaref.py", line 8, in <module>
    runfile('E:/Anyagok/Programozas/Python/projekts/gyak/Pyautogui/sima.py', wdir='E:/Anyagok/Programozas/Python/projekts/gyak/Pyautogui')
NameError: name 'runfile' is not defined
```

Why not?

Edit:
Got the idea of runfile() from: when running code in Spyder, in the console it displays e.g.:

```
runfile('E:/Anyagok/Programozas/Python/projekts/gyak/Pyautogui/simaref.py', wdir='E:/Anyagok/Programozas/Python/projekts/gyak/Pyautogui')
```

Comment: Spyder has a global namespace shared between your console and the script itself. It's likely that you imported runfile at some point in the past, somewhere, and that name is now permanently in the namespace so the name can always be resolved, even for code that wouldn't otherwise work. You should try explicitly importing it inside `simaref.py` and see if that fixes the issue outside of Spyder.

Comment: What's `runfile` and where does it come from? Why would you _expect_ it to be defined?

Comment: My guess is that this is related to the issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47738537/4799172) but can't be sure. Point 2 in my answer will make Spyder behave more rationally so that these issues don't slip under the radar until you take scripts out of the environment. Does it work?

Comment: @Aran-Fey When I run a script in Spyder, it shows in the Console the runfile() command, so I thought why not use it

Answer (score 0):

Working with roganjosh's answer:
Couldn't find where to import the runfile() command, maybe it's something built-in. So I changed simaref.py to the code below, and now it works.

```
exec(open("E:/Anyagok/Programozas/Python/projekts/gyak/Pyautogui/sima.py").read())
```

Comment: Huh, so it's a Spyder method? I'll have a look into that side

Comment: You can use [`runpy.run_path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/runpy.html#runpy.run_path) instead of that exec thing.

Comment: @Aray-Fey
why would it be better?

Comment: It's not necessarily better, but it's more versatile. It lets you set the `__name__`, for example, so you can easily run the script as `__main__`.