# Cant convert str to float in python 3.6

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, floating-point, type-conversion

I am getting this error "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable" when i am trying to convert a str to float inorder to do summation.

```
# To Find sum of no. s  seperated by commas in a string 
  t=''
  y=''
  z=""
  s = "1.23,2.4,3.123"
  for x in s:
     if x != ',':
         y += x
     else: 
         t = z
         z = y
         y = ''
  print("y=",y,"z=",z,"t=",t)
  y = float(y)
  z = float(z)
  t = float(t)
  print("Sum is =",y+z+t)
```

Screenshot of the error occurring when i run the code
[image: Screenshot of the error occurring when i run the code]

Comment: runs perfectly when i run it. you might want to use the [split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method

Comment: Somewhere you assigned a number to "float", though it isn't in the code you are showing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see that you ran that code in Spyder. That is a great environment, which I use, but it does have one disadvantage. Any variables you have defined are still defined at the start of your code.

Almost certainly you have defined a variable with the name `float` that holds a string value. So your program tries to execute `y = float(y)` but misunderstands the meaning of `float`. We could have seen that if you had your "variable explorer` window visible, rather than the "help" window in your screenshot.

Try your program again after closing and restarting Spyder and see if you still get that error. And from now on, avoid using standard names like `float` for your variables.

Comment: I listed two methods to solve/stop This issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47738537/builtin-function-not-working-with-spyder/47738834#47738834)