# 'TypeError: 'list' object is not callable', even though I am not renaming any built-in functions

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have this very simple code:

```
g = ('f','a')
h = list(g)
```

I get this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-87-7941c56fab04>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/Users/username/Desktop/untitled3.py', wdir='/Users/username/Desktop')

File "/Users/username/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

File "/Users/username/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "/Users/username/Desktop/untitled3.py", line 10, in <module>
h = list(g)

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Please excuse my ignorance; there must be something very fundamental that I am missing here. Can someone please help me understand what's going on? I ran out of things to try for this simple code.

I am running Python 3.6.0.

Comment: What are the outputs for `print(list)` and `print(type(list))`?

Comment: Cannot reproduce on 3.6.3. I guess there is more code around, right?

Comment: In your iPython you most likely created a list called *list*, therefore overriding the built-in `list`. So when calling your code, the context of that `list` is still in your iPython, so this is most likely where you are getting this error.

Comment: This is *exactly* why one shouldn't define variables with names such as `list` or `dict` ;)

Comment: I agree with  @idjaw never use any of the following:  vars( __ builtins __ )

Comment: You also have at least eight further lines of code which remain a mystery to the would-be answerer, according to the traceback message. You cannot expect to get a complete answer from partial information ;-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Builtin function not working with Spyder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47738537/builtin-function-not-working-with-spyder)

Answer (score 3):

To help you visualize this better. You probably did something like this in your iPython:

```
>>> list = [1, 2, 3]
>>> g = ('f', 'a')
>>> h = list(g)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

In doing that you set the literal list to the list *class*, therefore when trying to *call* it per `()`, you are getting this error since the literal `[]` does not have a `__call__` method:

```
>>> your_list = [1, 2, 3]
>>> your_list()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Calling the built-in *list* class will give you a `list` object. So, if you reset your interpreter, and try this, you will see further what is happening:

```
>>> a_list = list()
>>> a_list()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Comment: I reset the IDE (Spyder, by completely exiting the program), ran my code again, and it worked. I'm a little confused as to why this is happening. I assigned a certain list to the variable name 'list' previously; however, I re-wrote my code as shown above. At this point, the literal 'list' should no longer be referring to the list I declared previously, correct? So why would it give this kind of error? I'm just confused as to why Python is designed to work this way. Thanks.

Comment: @dxxg-syz35 when you are running in your iPython terminal, you are still within that same "global" scope when you did that `list = [1, 2, 3]` (or whatever you assigned to "list'). Because of that, when you "overrode" the built-in `list` object with your own `list`, your code is still within that same scope. Python lets you do this. You need to be aware of this. You won't get warned that you are overriding a built-in, unless you are using an IDE like PyCharm that will warn you in real-time while you are coding.

Comment: @dxxg-syz35 I gave you a duplicate I wrote that explains how to stop this happening. The behaviour is really unintuitive and I got bitten by it myself in Spyder

Answer (score 1):

I believe you must've used list as a variable in the source file. Here is a dump of me reproducing the error

```
>>> a = ('g','h')
>>> b = list(a)
>>> b
['g', 'h']
>>> list = [1,2]
>>> c = list(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Notice that when i defined 'b' before defining a variable called list it returned a list but there was an error when I tried to define 'c' as `list(a)`after naming a variable as list. It is because python is interpreting `list` keyword as a variable.